# How to connect react component library to local project and mirror changes?

Tags: reactjs, components, shared-libraries, duplicity

I have react project and I would like to adjust **react-image-gallery** component.

I cloned that repository from github and make couple of changes.

Unfortunately when I tried to use this component in my local project it is not possible.

*Is actually possible to use the fetched component from github separately in my local project and simply adjust it only locally?*

It shows me this kind of error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-image-gallery' in 'file'
```

I have dependency set like that in package.json:

```
"react-image-gallery": "file:../../react-image-gallery",
```

And when I want to use it I just import it like that:

```
import ImageGallery from "react-image-gallery";
```

Component:
https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery